Bose PC speakers volume randomly goes down (occurring on separate computers)
I have Bose Companion 2 Series III speakers where the volume randomly gets quiet for up to ~10 seconds randomly. I thought it was a Windows problem at first, but it is also occurring with my Macbook (Sonoma 14.6). I have a Windows 11 desktop PC hooked up to the "From Computer" port, and the Macbook hooked into the "Aux In" port. I haven't found any ways to reproduce the issue. I'm not even sure how to start diagnosing the issue or any fixes to try. The only hint I might have is that it seems to not occur if the Windows pc is off (but I'm not 100% sure on that). I also have not noticed the issue when the aux is playing from Android devices.
I've also tried the million different fixes suggested from google results like this
Thanks for any input!

If the speakers have that issue on all devices, look for a defect in the speaker.

It appears to have a carbon potentiometer volume control (VC). These devices become electrically "noisy", or even open circuit. Try wiggling the knob, turning it far counter-clockwise and far clockwise, a few times. If that helps (or makes the issue worse), consider using a contact cleaner, such as one of these examples, or replacing the VC.
Check the cable -- wiggle it, particularly at the plug end. If the sound changes, the last few cm of the cable can be cut, and a new plug put on (or replace the whole cable).
One other possibility -- not a defect in PC or speakers -- nearby cell phones can output a hefty RF signal every minute or two when trying to contact to a cell tower (i.e., to check for messages). Often, that is heard as a chirp or beep from wired speakers, but it can also cause dropouts. Make sure that all cellular devices are kept a few meters away from speakers, PC, and wiring to them.


Thanks for the tips! Good ideas! I'll try these out. Regarding point 3, I know that "chirp or beep" you mention, and I have not heard that occur with the speakers. I'll still try to do some tests by putting my cell phone right by the speakers and have texts/calls sent to me to see if I notice any effects.

The most powerful signal is sent by the cell phone to test connectivity to a tower; once a connection is made, the power is reduced to just the minimum needed for reliable connection. If there's a tower nearby, the steady-state signal will be far lower than the periodic test chirps.
